# Changing output text from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently printing table column names, filtered, but need to change the text for each. 
For instance, the following:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_columns);
echo implode(', ', array_keys( array_filter( $row )));
```

outputs:

```
column_one, column_two, column_five
```

What I haven't been able to achieve, without a lengthy if statement, is a way to have complete control over the output, such as changing each...

Expected output:

```
This is column one, and Column two, but this is column five
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Table structure:

```
Category
--------
user_id
live_out
live_in
short_term
weekday
weekend
unsure
```

Current output (based on user selection):

```
live_out, live_in, weekday
```

Desired output:

```
Yes as live-out, Yes as live-in, Yes for regular weekdays
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Perhaps provide some examples of your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The expected output is in the question. Will add title prior to it.

Comment: You need to define some sort of logic/relationship between the column names and the output. Right now, it's essentially arbitrary.

Comment: We need the exact logic.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clear that up. Maybe simplifying it? Example: Array output is "column_name" would like to change to "Column Name".

Comment: But it's not that simple because each column could be different. They are not all going to be ucwords/str_replace

Comment: Okay, so what _are_ they going to be? That's the logic definition that is needed. If the output is going to be arbitrary for each column name, then "a lengthy if statement" (or something along those lines) is probably what you need.

Comment: They are fairly arbitrary and there are a lot. I think you are right. I was hoping that wasn't going to be the case but it certainly seems like it

Comment: Would you be so nice to post your SQL table structure. I think you make thinks more complicated, then they have to be. You already have a columns in your db, right?

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch Thanks for your input. I edited question with one of the tables, output and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `echo implode(', ', array_keys( array_filter( $row )));`
The implode() uses the array to concatenate the keys to one string.

One solution would be to use string concatenation, when iterating the array:

```
$array = array_keys( array_filter( $row ))); // gets you the keys array

$string = 'This is ';
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $string .= $item . ', '; // append item to string with comma added
}
$string .= '. That's all.';

echo $string;
```

If you want custom text per item, you need to detect the item when iterating.
You might use if and strpos() for that, like so:

```
$string = 'This is ';
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $string .= $item . ', '; // append item to string with comma added

    if(false !== strpos($item, 'Column One')) { // look for Column One in $item
        $string .= ' (found column one)';
    }    
}
$string .= ' That's all.';

echo $string;
```

Replace:

```
$string = str_replace('Column One', 'Column XXX', $string);
```

works also for multiple items at once

```
$replace = array('Column One', 'Column Two');
$with = array('Column XX1', 'Column XX2');
$string = str_replace($replace, $with, $string);
```

Take care about `$string =` and `$string .=`.
The first assigns the value, the second appends the value.

**Based on your table structure**

```
$string = '';
foreach($array as $item)
{   
    if(false !== strpos($item, 'live_out')) { 
        $string .= 'Yes for '. $item . ', ';
    }

    if(false !== strpos($item, 'live_in')) { 
        $string .= 'Yes for '. $item . ', ';
    }

    if(false !== strpos($item, 'weekdays')) { 
        $string .= 'Yes for regular '. $item;
    }    
}   

echo $string;
```

Comment: This 2nd example is awesome. Thanks! I do have an issue or two in here though. I lose the filter (was filtering out values of 0). All columns show. Also how can I replace an item rather than the concatenation?

Comment: replacing works with str_replace(). i've added some lines of code

Comment: updated with an example based on live_out, live_in and weekdays

Comment: So in all cases for me, I don't know what the output will be. It's based on user selections. In this case I just build out if statements for each. Should I just find the final comma and replace with '' or is there an easier way of going about it? Since we don't know where the final item is we'll have a hanging punctuation mark

Comment: Yes, often the first and the final items need different handling. You might do that outside the foreach by appending or replacing. Simply replace a dangling punctuation or comma by nothing `''`;

Comment: Thanks! I'll just trim the string. Really appreciate your help. Your answer works out great!

Answer (score 0):

You can change each item in the array like this;

```
$column_names[0] = "Add this to the start of column one ". $column_names[0] . ", and this to the end of column one.";
```

0 is the first item in the array, and 1 is the second and so on.

Remember you need to do this to the array you get from array_keys in this case.

Otherwise you could make a function like this;

```
function addStrToArrayElements($array, $str_start, $str_end, $array_keys=NULL){
    foreach($array as $key => $item){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array_keys) ||  is_null($array_keys) ){
            $ret[$key] = $str_start.$item.$str_end;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

$array is the array you want the elements to change on, $str_start is the string to put in front of the item, $str_end the on behind the item, and $array_keys is an array of the keys of which elements you want changed, if you leave it blank, it will do the same to all elements of $array.

For the example you have above you would do this:

```
$column_names = array_keys($row);
addStrToArrayElements($column_names, 'This is ', ',', array(0));
addStrToArrayElements($column_names, ' and ', ',', array(1));
addStrToArrayElements($column_names, ' but this is ', '', array(2));
$output = implode('', $column_names);
echo str_replace('column_', 'column ', $output);
```

That should output

```
This is column one, and column two, but this is column five
```

Comment: The only issue here is that the array is variable. So determining each item couldn't be done manually

Comment: @Jamie
Well, then you need a "standard glue" for the ones in the middle, or an array of standard glues, which you could use rand() to choose from, and then you'd use count() to figure out which array item you need to add the ending to. [0] should always be the first item.

Comment: @Jamie You could also have an array of prefix and suffixes like this;
array('column_one'=>array('prefix goes here','suffix here'),'column_two'=>array('prefix for two is here','suffix for two is here'));
Then you'd loop through the columns with foreach, and get prefixes and suffixes to add onto the strings from that array mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have the following array called $array1 below:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("hey","its","me","so","what");
$newarray = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($array1 as $value)
{

  $newarray[] = "<span id=" . "color$i" . ">" . $value . "</span>";
  $i++;
}

echo implode(",",$newarray);
?>
```

You can use the algorithm to set different styles for all the columns using the spans created. So for instance you can set a style in the head or external stylesheet like so:

```
<style>
#color0{ color:red;}
#color1{ color:blue;}
#color2{ color:yellow;}
</style>
```

I tested this out and it seems to work just fine!

Comment: I didn't DV, but I'm considering it since this answer doesn't address the heart of the question (varying the output based on the value of each array element).

Comment: Okay I think 1 down-vote is enough though, lol. Let me re-read the question and answers.